# c# Memory leak system.timers

Tags: c#, memory, delegates, timer, memory-leaks

I'm currently writing a program which interacts with I/O devices and needed a method of polling the device every x amount of seconds in order to check the in/out connections. To do this i've used a button which creates a thread to do the polling, using a timer and timer event handles. However, i notice that in the task manager, it is slowly eating up more memory as time goes by. Below is some snippets of code that are (i think) relevant to my problem.

Button for creating thread:

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(start).Start();
    }
```

The thread that includes the timer:

```
        public void start()
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerElapsed);
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

The ElapsedEventHandler:

```
public void timerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        connect();
    }
```

And finally the method connect();:

```
public void connect()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(txtIPseg1.Text + "." + txtIPseg2.Text + "." + txtIPseg3.Text + "." + txtIPseg4.Text);
        int Port = int.Parse(txtPort.Text);
        string address = sb.ToString();

        //send data
        byte[] bData = new byte[71];
        bData[0] = 240;
        bData[1] = 240;
        bData[2] = 0;
        bData[3] = 1;
        bData[68] = 240;
        bData[69] = 240;
        bData[70] = this.CalculateCheckSum(bData);

        try
        {
            byte[] result = this.SendCommandResult(address, Port, bData, 72);
            if (result != null)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    txtOutput1.Text = (result[4] == 0x00 ? "HIGH" : "LOW"); // runs on UI thread
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

I'm pretty sure the leak is either coming from the timer, or the anon delegate used in the method connect();, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't the GC not running?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a memory leak? Maybe the GC just didn't run yet, so no reason to panic.

Comment: It's unrelated to the presumed memory leak, but why start a new thread just to start a timer?  The thread appears to end as soon as the timer is created, anyway.

Comment: how often does the GC run...? are we talking minutes? i'll leave it running for 10 and see what happens.

Comment: @SteveDog surely without putting it in a thread, my main thread would just come to a standstill and i wouldn't be able to do anything else with it. I'm constantly polling the device so it runs for as long as the program is running.

Comment: @SteveDog: Good point. How can the timer even fire?

Comment: @KendallFrey I was wondering the same thing.  There's no reference kept to the timer.  The timer has a reference back to the event handler, but I wouldn't expect that to keep the GC from destroying it.

Comment: noob alert right here. what would you guys suggest i do?

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter The System.Timers.Timer class raises the Elapsed event on a new thread from a thread pool each time it fires.  It doesn't need to be in a different thread when you start it.

Comment: so instead of starting a new thread onclick of the button, i should just call the method instead?

Comment: You should create a single instance of the timer, as a private member of your class.  That way your object will keep a reference to it and disable it when you want it to stop firing.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer by default starts its own thread.  Your current code starts a thread which starts a thread.  How much debugging have you actually done exactly?  I guarantee you that there is no a memory leak in System.Timers.Timer at least not one you THINK you might have discovered.

Comment: can you perhaps give me an example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new timer each time the button is clicked.  Also, you are not keeping a reference to it, so it will be destroyed by the garbage collector.  There is no need to start the timer on a new thread because the timer will raise the Elapsed event on a new thread.

```
class Form1 ...
{
    private System.Timers.Timer timer = null;

    public void start()
    {
    if (timer == null)
        {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerElapsed);
        }
    timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    ...
}
```

As far as a memory leak goes, I wouldn't assume there is a memory leak just because you see the memory usage fluctuating seemingly randomly while your application is running.  That is normal behavior when you are running inside of a complex framework like .NET.  Each time the timer fires, it's calling your connect method which creates new objects. Those objects will stay in memory until the garbage collector gets around to cleaning them up. As such, it's not at all surprising to see the memory creep up and then all of a sudden after a few minutes, drop back down again. I wouldn't suspect a problem unless it keeps growing out of control over a much longer period of time.

It's also strange the way you are using the StringBuilder class.  What you are doing:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(txtIPseg1.Text + "." + txtIPseg2.Text + "." + txtIPseg3.Text + "." + txtIPseg4.Text);
string address = sb.ToString();
```

is no better (in fact it's a bit worse), than just doing this:

```
string address = txtIPseg1.Text + "." + txtIPseg2.Text + "." + txtIPseg3.Text + "." + txtIPseg4.Text;
```

If you're looking for a more efficient, and possibly easier to read way to do it, try something like this

```
string address = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", txtIPseg1.Text, txtIPseg2.Text, txtIPseg3.Text, txtIPseg4.Text);
```

Nothing, however, is jumping out at me as being anything that would cause a memory leak, so unless you have good reason to think so, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: having implemented your method (which works just fine), I'm still getting the slow increase in memory, about 4k a second. You could be right about the normal behaviour, so I'll leave it running for a while and see if anything absurd occurs. i've also just noticed this memory usage is also happening before starting the process. maybe it's just me being paranoid.

Comment: Are you looking at the process's memory usage or the total memory usage? You won't get any useful information by watching total memory usage.

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter Each time the timer fires, it's calling your connect method which creates new objects.  Those objects will stay in memory until the garbage collector gets around to cleaning them up.  As such, it's not at all surprising to see the memory creep up and then all of a sudden after a few minutes, drop back down again.  I wouldn't suspect a problem unless it keeps growing out of control over a much longer period of time.

Comment: i'm going to leave it running a little while. it starts at about 4900k after clicking connect. i'll get back to you after i'm done testing a little.

Comment: after a short period of time i imagined the GC would have acted by now if it was going to. it has risen now to over 7000k, which is a 40% increase in memory in 7 minutes. To test that is coming from the timer, i have tried changing the button so that it manually calls connect() onclick, and this has stopped the memory usage increasing like it does using the timer. is it perhaps because the timer is getting larger and takes more memory to hold its current time? would resetting the timer do anything?

Comment: I guarantee the timer isn't using that much space to store it's time. I am quite sure it doesn't use over 8 bytes.

Comment: i figured as much. just seems strange because the program doesn't really DO any awful lot at the minute..nothing pops out at me as leaky, but it's still increasing yet. at 8k now.

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter A few suggestions: 1/ Try calling `GC.Collect();` at the end of your `connect` method, 2/ Ensure that the method ends and isn't stuck somewhere (you can check by adding a breakpoint or displaying a message), 3/ provide the code of the `CalculateCheckSum` and `SendCommandResult` methods. If there's indeed a leak, it might be there.

Comment: it seems as though the memory usage seems to have capped at a certain point, 7812k to be precise. this may be a relieve, but ill start it again from fresh and see if it caps at around the same number again. has anyone had this happen before?