# C# memory leaks due to timers?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, timer, garbage-collection

I'm just starting in C# and this is my first question so apologies if this is dumb or the wrong way to ask..

I have a list of timers:

`private List<MyTimerClass> MyTimerClassList = new List<MyTimerClass>();`

where `MyTimerClass` just contains a value to keep track of the ID of this timer and a method to initialize it:

`timer = new System.Timers.Timer();`

and I'm setting up these timers in a standard way with an `ElapsedEventHandler`:

```
foreach (var p in AnotherList)
{
    var t = new MyTimerClass();
    t.init_timer();
    t.id = MyOtherClass.ID;
    t.timer.Interval = p.Interval;
    t.timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((source, e) => RunMyTimerEvent(source, e, p));
    t.timer.Enabled = true;
    MyTimerClassList.Add(t);
};
```

These timers are meant to keep running indefinitely and the event handlers run some asynchronous web stuff. Sometimes, the program may get some info that requires it to reschedule, add or remove any or all of these timers, so I have another timer event that regularly checks an update schedule and re configures any of the above timers if needed:

```
// first check to see see if a timer should be removed                
foreach (var t in MyTimerClassList)
{
    if (!(UpdatedListofTimers.Exists(p => p.ID == t.id)))
    {
        t.timer.Stop();
        t.timer.Dispose();

    }
}
// then check to see if any of the timer intervals has been changed
foreach (var t in UpdatedAnotherList)
{
    var item = MyTimerClassList.Find(p => p.id == MyTimerClass.ID);
    if (item != null)
    {
        if (item.timer.Interval != (t.interval * 1000))
        {
            item.timer.Stop();
            item.timer.Interval = (t.Interval * 1000);
            item.timer.Start();
        }
    }
    // leaves us with adding a new timer
    else {
        var n = new MyTimerClass();
        n.init_timer();
        n.id = t.ID;
        n.timer.Interval = t.interval * 1000;
        n.timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, ev) => RunMyTimerEvent(sender, ev, t));
        n.timer.Enabled = true;
        MyTimerClassList.Add(n);
    }
};
```

The code works; it works fine, timers are updated and rescheduled and reconfigured as they should be, they fire off the events and do their stuff. The timer handler event is basically a call to a method that starts off a task:

```
public void RunMyTimerEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e, AnotherList x)
{

    Task<int> t = Task.Run(() => AsyncProcessClass.SomeAsyncStuff(x));
    t.Wait();
    t.Dispose();
}
```

The problem is that there is huge memory leak, memory use ramps up very quickly and doesn't get garbage collected even with a hard call to `GC.Collect`. Inside the `async` process that I'm calling, there aren't any memory leaks or handlers that aren't disposed of (and I'm aware that you don't necessarily have to dispose of stuff, the garbage collector is smart enough to know whats no longer referenced).

If, instead of reconfiguring the timers when I get an update, I delete them all and recreate them from scratch, the memory leak goes away. Am I doing something completely wrong here ? Instead of changing the timer interval on the fly as it were, do you have to delete it and create a new one ? Can another timer event not reconfigure a different timer ? Is it the weak reference problem with the method inside the event handler, that it never gets marked for garbage collection ? I don't understand weak references that well, at least not enough to have tried it. Maybe I'm doing something that's obviously wrong ?

Comment: Just a wild guess, it's due to the "SomeAsyncStuff"? What's SomeAsyncStuff??

Comment: Try unregistering  n.timer.Elapsed before you change internal.  and register it again once after changing interval.

Comment: try check this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654253/c-sharp-memory-leak-system-timers

Comment: how should I unregister n.timer.Elapsed ? It's using an anonymous lambda function

Comment: What do you mean by "I delete them all"? Clear the list? Aren't you removing them from the list anyway? How much IDs do you have anyway? If you dispose a timer *and* remove any references to it (i.e. remove it from the list), it should get collected. Event handler references work the other way around: the if you attach a handler as a method in object B to an event of an object A, then object A will keep the object B alive, i.e. a timer will keep alive whichever object contains the `RunMyTimerEvent` method. There is absolutely no reason to have your own "timer pool", like you're doing now.

Comment: @groo re: There is absolutely no reason to have your own "timer pool": you're right, I have changed it to use one single dispatch - tick - timer and trigger all events from that.